# querying products, categories through the associative table

Tags: sql, database

I have the 2 usual tables, products and categories, and because of the Many to Many relationship I created a key mapping table that relates both. This associative table is for example just like this:

```
id  product_id  category_id
1      2         4
2      2         6
3      3         4
etc
```

where they are the Foreign keys to the respective `product_id` and `category_id` Primary Keys.

So now I am trying to write a query to test results. Normally I want it to show me some products belonging to a specific category. But I have tried several queries, yet it tells me that I have an error in mysql syntax.

```
select products.name
from products
join producto-categoria
on producto-categoria.product_id = products.id
join categorias
on producto-categoria.category_id = categorias.id
where categorias.id = 3
limit 100
```

I actually first created the structure in phpmyadmin and then uploaded the  respective csv files and then finally linked them through their FK having created indexes in the associative table (also called key mapping table) and I didn't have any error while it created the FK links. InnoDB as an engine.

Comment: Rename your tables so they don't have hyphens in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `producto-categoria` to `productocategoria`.  The hyphen is causing a syntax error because it is interpreted as a minus sign.  You could also escape the name, but it is better practice to have "simple" names rather than names that contain non-standard characters.

Then two more things:

- Use table table aliases.
- Get rid of the join to `categorias`, because the table is not used.

So:

```
select p.name
from products p join
     productocategoria pc
    on pc.product_id = p.id
where pc.category_id = 3
limit 100
```

Comment: thank you! I have to wait 10 minutes before I can approve it. You are totally right in your points. The hyphen made me suspect but it didnt fully wake me up to realization. Right too about the aliases,

Comment: I am going to buy your book. The title is highly interesting and I actually do my best to use sql to create sales reports. Definitively a must read for me.